# BIND create reverse zone for /21 block

Tags: bind, reverse-dns, dns.ptr

LINUX, BIND9

I have a network which sits in /21 block and would like to make a reverse zone, I would like some guidance to know where to look to create the reverse zone file.

I could make seperate files for each of the 3rd octet block, example: 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.zone + 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.zone +.... 7.168.192.in-addr.arpa.zone. But how would I combine this into one file and put all the PTR records in the same place?

Answer (score -1):

Create a zone like you would for any other host/domain.

Lets call it `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.zone`:

```
$TTL    3600
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@   IN SOA  primary.domain.name.    root.localhost. (
            2016010220  ; Serial
            3600        ; Refresh (1hr)
            300         ; Retry (15min)
            3600000     ; Expire (5 weeks 6 days 16 hours)
            3600  )     ; Minimum (1hr)

; authoritative servers
            IN  NS  primary.domain.name.
            IN  NS  secondary.server.name.
            IN  NS  slave.dome.domain.
            IN  NS  ...
            IN  NS  ...

; RRs
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR host.domain.name.
2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR nameserver.some.domain.
3.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR another.host.name.

...

253.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN  PTR mx.mail.exchange.
254.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN  PTR web.server.domain.
```

Then list it as you would any other zone in your `named.conf` file.
That's really all you need.

**EDIT:**

It occurs to me based on your respnse in the comments section that you might not be familiar with [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)

Here's a [CIDR calculator](https://account.arin.net/public/cidrCalculator) from the *authority* on Internet Numbers ([ARIN](https://arin.net/)).

As such. Here's another way to *describe* an entire block of (IP) `256` addresses:

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

The notation is the same as described above. But you're now able to "group" blocks of varying quantity in each delegation.

You can also *describe* "blocks" of IP addresses thusly:

```
0-256    IN NS master.some.domain
```

or

```
1.0-3.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR  host.domain.name.
```

In your RR glue (as above).

See also [The BIND Administration Guide](https://dnswatch.com/dns-docs/BIND-administration-guide/) for the proprietary `$GENERATE` macro for creating sequences of PTR records (assumes a "classfull" list).

**Lastly**, an [RFC2317](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt) example you might find helpful

```
$ORIGIN 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN      SOA     my-ns.my.domain. hostmaster.my.domain. (...)
;...
;  <<0-127>> /25
0/25            NS      ns.A.domain.
0/25            NS      some.other.name.server.
;
1               CNAME   1.0/25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
2               CNAME   2.0/25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
3               CNAME   3.0/25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
;
;  <<128-191>> /26
128/26          NS      ns.B.domain.
128/26          NS      some.other.name.server.too.
;
129             CNAME   129.128/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
130             CNAME   130.128/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
131             CNAME   131.128/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
;
;  <<192-255>> /26
192/26          NS      ns.C.domain.
192/26          NS      some.other.third.name.server.
;
193             CNAME   193.192/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
194             CNAME   194.192/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
195             CNAME   195.192/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.

$ORIGIN 0/25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN      SOA     ns.A.domain. hostmaster.A.domain. (...)
@               NS      ns.A.domain.
@               NS      some.other.name.server.
;
1               PTR     host1.A.domain.
2               PTR     host2.A.domain.
3               PTR     host3.A.domain.
```

HTH

Comment: that example is fine for 255.255.255.0/24, which is only 256 IPs. This range 255.255.248.0/21 contains 2048 IPs. It ranges from 192.168.0.255 -> 192.168.7.255. How do you do all that in one file?

Comment: Sure. But this was only an example that you could build on for your needs. I have no idea how you delegate your /21. Are you subbing out any of it? Is one server authoritative for the entire /21? Too many questions I'd need to ask, to write your RR glue for you. Can you update your original post to be a bit more specific as to how you intend to *delegate* your /21? :)